# How to GroupBy and Order by multiple fields with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have a DataTable (dtResult) with 4 fields, id, store, sku and qty.  Unfortunately there are a lot of duplicates in the DataTable that I want to remove (qtys are diff, but other fields are the same).

I want to sort the DataTable by id asc, store asc, sku asc, and group by id, store and sku so I would have a list of unique records.

IDEALLY I would like to overwrite the existing DataTable with the results of the query, and qty can just be 0 for everything.  I have the sort, and currently I'm putting it into a new DataTable:

```
var dtUniqueResults = dtResult.AsEnumerable()
    .OrderBy(r => r.Field<string>("id"))
    .ThenBy(r => r.Field<string>("store"))
    .ThenBy(r => r.Field<string>("sku"))
    .CopyToDataTable();
```

I don't understand how to group with LINQ.  I think I need to add something like this, but it's not working.

```
var dtUniqueResults = dtResult.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(n => n.Field<string>("id"),
             n => n.Field<string>("store"),
             n => n.Field<string>("sku")
    )
    .OrderBy(r => r.Field<string>("id"))
    .ThenBy(r => r.Field<string>("store"))
    .ThenBy(r => r.Field<string>("sku"))
    .CopyToDataTable();
```

I've read a lot of posts, and I see several ways of doing it.  However it seems the two that are suggested the most are these, but they seem so different it just confuses me more.

```
GroupBy( x => new { x.Column1, x.Column2 })

AND

GroupBy(x=> new { x.Column1, x.Column2 }, (key, group) => new 
{ 
  Key1 = key.Column1,
  Key2 = key.Column2,
  Result = group.ToList() 
});
```

Comment: Did you see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20698715/how-to-group-by-on-multiple-columns-from-datatable-with-linq)

Comment: So...  `.GroupBy (n => new { n.Field<string>("id"), n.Field<string>("store"), n.Field<string>("sku") })`  ??

Comment: Yes, that how you do the group by multiple fields

Comment: Great, I'll give it a shot in the morning.

Comment: I'm getting "EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> does not contain a definition for 'groupby'

Comment: do you have `using System.Linq;`?

Comment: @huMptyduMpty (facepalm) Ok, fixed that, but now I'm getting "Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access" on everything between the {  }s

Comment: I think error is self explanatory `.GroupBy (n => new { Id =n.Field<string>("id")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to filter out duplicates, try the following query:

```cs
var dtUniqueResults = dtResult.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(n => new 
        { 
            Id = n.Field<string>("id"),
            Store = n.Field<string>("store"),
            Sku = n.Field<string>("sku")
        }
    )
    .SelectMany(g => g.Take(1)) // get from group only one record
    .CopyToDataTable();
```